# reloading page with new function AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a page that displays the latest images.
i am using an AJAX request to sort these images :

```
$('#trier').on('click', function() {        // When i click on button to validate Sort out
var b = document.getElementById('genre').value;  // parameter Sort out : genre 
$.post('index.php', {y: b}, function(data) {
location.reload(); // reload page with pictures sorted out
});
});
```

and this is what my function that sorts the images out looks like :

```
if(isset($_POST['y'])){              // if they is a sorting out request
function latest($n) {
$genre= $_POST['y'];
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "artlibr1_default", "azerty123", "artlibr1_01");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE genre='$genre' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $n, 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 return $list['path'];
}
}}else{                             // default display 
function latest($n) {
$genre= $_POST['y'];
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "artlibr1_default", "azerty123", "artlibr1_01");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $n, 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 return $list['path'];
}
}
```

( only the sql statement changes)
So the problem is that i need the page to reload with the `$_POST['y']` data; but at the moment the page is just reloading and doesn't have `$_POST['y']` data.

Comment: You're getting content with ajax, and then reloading the page with `location.reload()`, loosing the content you just fetched ?

Comment: @adeneo i am sending out data with ajax, but then want to reload page with this new data in consideration; but ajax doesn't work like that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you don't use ajax correctly.
Maybe you should edit your code

```
$('#trier').on('click', function() {        // When i click on button to validate Sort out
    var b = document.getElementById('genre').value;  // parameter Sort out : genre 
    $.post('index.php', {y: b}, function(data) {
        $('#div-need-load-image').html(data) // reload page with pictures sorted out
    });
});
```

Or if you want append image to div, you can try `.append()` instead of `.html()`

`$('#div-need-load-image').append(data)`

Comment: .html() looks like the solution !  I should have thought of this but my javascript knowledge is poor :S ! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

1. Makes an HTTP request from JavaScript
2. Gets some data from a database with PHP
3. Sends that data from PHP to the JavaScript
4. The JavaScript *ignores* that data and reloads the page (with the original GET request)

If you want to reload the page. **Don't use Ajax**. The point of Ajax is that you make an HTTP request without reloading the page.

If you want to use the data you get back, then don't use `location.reload`, take the value of `data` and do something with it.

Comment: okey makes sense thanks ! but i could use AJAX to hide all elements that don't correspond to sort out parameters tho ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the entire page you could clear the content of of `#genre` and replace it with the data returned from your ajax function.

Comment: #genre is just a select form

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
location.reload();
```

you should use

```
location.href = %Construct the URL you want to reload%
```